# How to update duty cycle once only?

Tags: c, adc, pwm, stm32cubeide, stm32f1

I am programming STM32 chip in C and trying to control duty cycle of PWM cycle depending on ADC read value. with below implementation; I am able to set different duty cycle along with ADC value. But I realized that it repeatedly sets duty cycle of PWM as it's in the while loop.. but I need to keep this while loop as I need to constantly check ADC. My expectation is that it only sets single duty cycle (or desired duty cycle) then stops sending data to PWM and ready for the next change from ADC. How should I achieve that? Let me know if I can help clarifying the question. Thank you

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{   
    int adc_val = 3000; 
    int init_duty = 250;
    int var = 0;
    int data = 0;
        
    int foldit(int var){
        if (var <1200) return 0;
        else if (var >= 1200 && var <= 2000) return 1;
        else if (var > 2000) return 2;
    }
    
    int toSend(int data){
        static int old_duty = -1;
        if(init_duty != old_duty){
            printf("sending data : %d\n", init_duty);
            old_duty = init_duty;
            //TIM1->CCR1 = init_duty;
        }
        else{
            printf("not sending data : %d\n", init_duty);
            //not sending datat 
        }
    }
    
    while(1){
        // adc val = SPI_Raed_ADC_RxData();
        switch(foldit(adc_val)){
            case 0:
                toSend(init_duty);
                printf("current duty cycle set to default :%d\n", init_duty);
                break;
            
            case 1:
                if(init_duty <= 200){
                    //send_UART(setPWMDutyCycle(init_duty));
                    printf("current duty cycle 2.0 :%d\n", init_duty);
                    toSend(init_duty);
                }
                else{
                    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
                        init_duty = init_duty -10;
                        //send_UART(setPWMDutyCycle(init_duty));
                        if(init_duty <=200)
                        {
                            break;    
                        }
                        printf("current duty cycle 2.1 : %d\n", init_duty);
                        toSend(init_duty);
                    }    
                }
                break;
            
            case 2:
                init_duty = 400;
                //send_UART(setPWMDutyCycle(init_duty));
                printf("current duty cycle 3 : %d\n", init_duty);
                toSend(init_duty);
                break;
            
            default:
                break;
        }
        
    }
}
```

I expect to send data to PWM using `send_UART(setPWMDutyCycle(init_duty))`only once or update until it reaches desired value.

Comment: Aside: `foldit()` has "holes" at `1200` and `2000`. It is those values which will `return 9999;` Should (for example) the second line be the simpler `if (var < 2000) return 1;` ? Under what condition did you intend it to `return 9999;`?

Comment: @WeatherVane you are correct. I will correct the post. return 9999 is not necessary. Second line will remain the same. I just corrected range including 1200 and 2000 and removed return 9999

Comment: Correct the code on your own machine: your supposed correction was faulty too.

Comment: @WeatherVane corrected and ran again. I think that there is no more fault code in the case and it dose set duty cycle as what it's supposed to. But it keeps updating same value infinitely as it's kept in while loop along with ADC read function.

Comment: Why not just remember the old value for `init_duty` and _not_ set a new PWM unless it changes? What about: `void set_duty(int init_duty) { static int old_duty = -1; if (init_duty != old_duty) { send_UART(setPWMDutyCycle(init_duty)); old_duty = init_duty; } }`

Comment: @CraigEstey I updated the code as you suggested. Does it more make sense? isn't it  more efficient to implement interrupt in this case ?

Comment: Yes, use of an interrupt is orthogonal to using the comparison. You can read the ADC via interrupt if the system will allow an interrupt when the ADC changes rather than polling it. In that case, you can _still_ use the `old_duty` comparson. If reading the ADC is a "heavyweight" operation, and you can't use an interrupt on it, you could just poll it less frequently. That is, you poll it only at regular intervals. Sometimes, setting a timer interrupt and doing the read ADC and setting of the PWM from the timer ISR is a way to go.

Comment: For PWM, if you can set a timer interrupt with adequate frequency, you can eliminate ADC polling altogether. Say, you must update the PWM every 1 ms (_if_ the output value changes), setting a 1 ms timer interrupt will work. Then, your main loop is free to do other useful things, rather than spending most of its time polling the ADC (only to have 90% of them be an effective NOP). Adjust the timer interval to whatever you need.

Comment: @CraigEstey above implementation will work but where should I start for writing interrupt..? I am not too familiar with embedded systems. I happened to include STM32 mcu on my PCB to test gate driver ICs so I didn't really need to go too much details in programming. But any recommendation would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You'd have to move the whole `switch` statement/block you have in `main` into a function. Let's call it `do_one_full_adc_read_and_pwm_update` :-) (and make the stack variables into globals). Then, you have to set up a timer: A web search for that: https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&as_q=stm32+timer+interrupt&as_epq=&as_oq=&as_eq=&as_nlo=&as_nhi=&lr=&cr=&as_qdr=all&as_sitesearch=&as_occt=any&as_filetype=&tbs= provides many examples and tutorials. When you have a timer ISR (interrupt service routine) working, just have it call that "function with the very long name" ;-).

Comment: You could do this in steps. Create the function and the globals. Then, to verify it, you can use it to poll. In `main`, it is now `while (1) { do_one_full_adc_read_and_pwm_update(); do_other_useful_stuff(); }` Then, when the timer ISR is working, move the call to `do_one_full_adc_read_and_pwm_update` from the loop in `main` into the ISR function. Kaboom! You're done :-)

Comment: @CraigEstey Thanks for your help. I will try to implement and come back with updates.